# can you turn a visible laser pointer into a uv one?

Tags: laser, uv

I was wondering if there is anything I can do to make a visible laser pointer uv with (or without) messing with the laser. like if I simply shot the laser pointer through some device or screen that would shorten the wavelength? thanks for any help.

Comment: Green lasers are often produced by frequency pumping a red laser, but it is not as simple as you would hope. You would need to be a photonics engineer to attempt this. Also, most materials also absorb UV wavelength which means UV-anything either doesn't exist or is really REALLY expensive.

Comment: https://www.rp-photonics.com/frequency_doubling.html

Comment: Sorry, it's not called frequency pumping. It's called frequency doubling. You can't just pick whatever multiplier ratio you want.

Comment: i think that you could achieve the desired effect by moving the laser pointer at near `c`

Comment: @jsotola I can think of more productive uses for such technology.

Comment: that makes sense. thanks, will read up

Comment: @DKNguyen you are right ... winning drag races should be priority ... lol

Answer (score 1):

Lasers can be frequency doubled using nonlinear media. However, the process is not simple, and typically requires precise alignment and materials engineered for the specific wavelength or else extremely high power.

In spite of the cost, this method is used to double 532nm lasers to generate 266nm (or in reality to quadruple 1064nm lasers). For longer near-UV wavelengths, it's usually cheaper to buy a direct UV source. There are fairly cheap laser diodes above 350nm.

Comment: So I can buy a UV laser diode? I'm trying to find or make/modify some sort of laser like beam that is high enough to not be technically visible. Thanks

Comment: @Af91 did you google it?

Comment: https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=5400